# Dockerized Wordpress environment has load issues and service disruption

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm running a Wordpress environment based on a few containers:

- Nginx Proxy (Jwilder)
- Wordpress Apache PHP 7.4 (official image)
- MySQL Database (official image)

The VPS is an Ubuntu 22 Server LTS with 4GB/RAM and 2 vCPU.
The website (Woocommerce based) works fine normally, not exceptionally fast but still ok, but if you just open multiple tabs (~10) and hit reload the message "Error Establishing a Database Connection” pops up, even if containers don't crash and keep running. Then it just takes a few seconds to correctly reload the website.

I reduced MySQL memory impact database side (see https://github.com/alexanderkoller/low-memory-mysql), lowered mpm_prefork settings Apache side (mostly number of processes and children), but still the issue is there.
Logs are clean, except for those obvious 500 errors when the db can't be reached.
I think I followed about 30 different topics out there, without finding anything about my specific case.

Following my docker-compose, quite basic:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY=false
    volumes:
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - lets-certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - ./conf.d/client_max_upload_size.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/client_max_upload_size.conf
    restart: always
    networks:
      net_external:
      web_internal:
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100m"
        max-file: "10"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    environment:
        VIRTUAL_HOST: x
        LETSENCRYPT_HOST: x
        PMA_HOSTS: x
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: x
        UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - net_external
      - mysql
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100m"
        max-file: "10"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: x
      MYSQL_USER: x
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: x
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: x
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mysql
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100m"
        max-file: "10"

  wordpress:
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: x
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: x
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: x
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: x
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true);
      VIRTUAL_HOST: x
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: x
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./wordpress-build/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./prod:/var/www/html
      - './uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini'
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - web_internal
      - prod_mysql
      - wp_external
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100m"
        max-file: "10"

volumes:
  html:
  mysql:
  dhparam:
  vhost:

networks:
  web_internal:
    internal: true
  mysql:
    internal: true
  net_external:
    external: true
  wp_external:
    external: true
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Ram was the culprit, and also MySQL image standard that expects a more performing host.
Posted link is correct for low ram scenario, but max_connections has to be raised.

EDIT:
Relevant settings in my.cnf

```
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M
innodb_log_buffer_size=256K
query_cache_size=32M
max_connections=200
key_buffer_size=8
thread_cache_size=8
host_cache_size=0
innodb_ft_cache_size=1600000
innodb_ft_total_cache_size=32000000
thread_stack=131072
sort_buffer_size=32K
read_buffer_size=8200
read_rnd_buffer_size=8200
max_heap_table_size=16K
tmp_table_size=1K
bulk_insert_buffer_size=0
join_buffer_size=128
net_buffer_length=1K
innodb_sort_buffer_size=64K
binlog_cache_size=4K
binlog_stmt_cache_size=4K
performance_schema = off
```

Comment: What is your NEW RAM size and vCPU's?

Comment: Same RAM and CPU, only adjusted mysql settings.

Comment: Would you share with us the my.cnf [mysqld] changes in the form of 

    variable_name=xxx  # from xxx 
    variable_name=xxx  # from xxx

Thank you.

Comment: I'll edit the post.

Comment: When your system becomes popular and you need better performance, view my profile and get in touch, plase.